# Cypher: How to optimize a search in a browser (maybe using parameters)

Tags: neo4j

Well, I have to run the following query (Neo4j comm. ed. 3.0.12 on Docker)

the caveat is that the calendar name has unknown format:
    1) firstname + " " + lastname + "-" + specialization
    2) lastname + " " + firstname + "-" + specialization

```
:PARAM name: "Di Pietro Chiara - Gynecologist"     

MERGE (_200:`person` {`lastname`: "Di Pietro", `firstname`: "Chiara", `birthdate`: "1984/03/25"})

MERGE (_cal_445:`calendar` { :`X-VR-CALNAME` = $name })-[:`belongs_to a`]-(_per_445:`person`) 
WHERE $name = _per_445.firstname + " " + _per_445.lastname
   OR $name = (_per_445.nome + " " + _per_445.cognome)
RETURN _cal_445, _per_445
```

The query, and some different variants, doesn't run. Sometimes returns an error, and sometimes destroys the browser layout on the screen,

Surely there is something wrong but I was unable to find and correct.
The part of confronting against two inverted format: how could be optimized?
Why the PARAM declaration generate an error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your query is not valid :

```
MERGE (_cal_445:`calendar` { :`X-VR-CALNAME` = $name })
```

You should replace it by this :

```
MERGE (_cal_445:`calendar` { `:X-VR-CALNAME`:$name })
```

Moreover, you are doing a `MERGE` with the value `$name` that is also on the `WHERE` cluse. It's just not allowed ...

If you replace the merge by a match, your query will work :

```
MERGE (_200:`person` {`lastname`: "Di Pietro", `firstname`: "Chiara", `birthdate`: "1984/03/25"})
WITH _200
MATCH (_cal_445:`calendar` { `:X-VR-CALNAME`: $name })-[:`belongs_to a`]-(_per_445:`person`) 

WHERE $name = _per_445.firstname + " " + _per_445.lastname
   OR $name = (_per_445.nome + " " + _per_445.cognome)

RETURN _cal_445, _per_445
```

Comment: Well, I changed the query, replacing wiyh your sample, but nothing changed.

Moreover, the browser doesn't respond with an error, but with a red line containing: "Type :help commands for a list of available commands.